# I am attempting to get VS code with the PHP xdebug plugin to work with a docker container website

Tags: php, docker, visual-studio-code, nginx, docker-compose

I am attempting to get VS code with the PHP xdebug plugin to work with a docker container website.

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 and using VS Code 1.86.0

I am running nginx, mysql and an App in separate docker containers. They are talking to each other no problem.

I am basically following a tutorial using VS Code with the xdebug plugin. The tutorial I am following is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7YuYxbYd3P0)

I have xdebug installed as a PHP module and I can see the xdebug info page when I run xdebug_info(). So this is all fine.

I have VS Code listening on port 9003.

I launch a page which is on the site using Chrome with xdebug helper. I expect it to open the relevant page on my site for debugging. But nothing happens.

I will list my docker file, my YML config file, my nginx file and my xdebug configuation file below with the hope that someone may understand what the problem is.

dockerfile

```
FROM php:8.3.2-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    curl \
    zip \
    vim \
    unzip \
    libicu-dev

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN apt update && apt install -y libicu-dev 
RUN docker-php-ext-configure intl
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql

RUN pecl install xdebug \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

COPY ./xdebug.ini "${PHP_INI_DIR}/conf.d"

WORKDIR /var/www
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ""
      dockerfile: dockerfile
    container_name: gio-project-app
    restart: always
    working_dir: /var/www/
    extra_hosts:
      - host.docker.internal:host-gateway
    volumes:
      - ../:/var/www
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.19-alpine
    container_name: gio-project-nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8002:80
    volumes:
      - ../:/var/www
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
  db:
    container_name: gio-project-db
    image: mysql:8.0
    volumes:
      - ./storage/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - 3308:3306
```

nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php;
    server_name localhost;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_page 404 /index.php;
    root /var/www/public;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }
}
```

xdebug.ini

```
zend_extension=xdebug
xdebug.mode=develop,debug
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.discover_client_host=0
xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal
```

The site launches fine and I can access the MySQL DB.

If you require any other information I will gladly provide it.

PS after looking at various questions in this area I have mashed some of the xdebug.ini files together with the hope that this would make it work.

It didn't work - anyway here is the updated xdebug file and also a change I made to the YML file.

Updated  xdebug

```
zend_extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20230831/xdebug.so
xdebug.mode=develop,debug
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.discover_client_host=1
xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal 
xdebug.client_port=9003
xdebug.remote_log="/usr/local/var/log/xdebug.log"
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
```

Added to YML file

```
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

And launch.json file

```
  "version": "0.2.0",
  // server -> local
  "pathMappings": {
    "/home/clive/www/learn.local/gio/src": "/var/www"

  }
}
```